# Shell Scripting - Mi script funciona en terminal como comando, pero no en fichero como script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

tengo un script con este contenido:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/sh
# reset jetbrains ide evals

 PATH_FILE='~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.1/'


 rm -rf ${PATH_FILE}eval
 echo "rm -rf ${PATH_FILE}eval"

echo "*******************************************"
echo "**       PHP-STORM  +30 DÍAS!!           **"
echo "*******************************************"
```

Basicamente, esta borrando un fichero en mi carpeta personal, pero no funciona.

En cambio, si lo uso literalmente en la consola :

```
rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.1/eval
```

Funciona a la perfeccion, a que se puede estar debiendo ?

La forma en la que estoy ejecutando mi script es mediante el terminal :

```
sh /home/$USER/Documentos/scripts/phpstorm_reset_trial.sh
```

Lo pondre en el crontab una vez funcione

Comment: ¿Qué significa _No funciona_? Sale algún error? Ponlo en la pregunta. No sale nada? indícalo en la pregunta. Estalla tu PC? Dilo en la pregunta. Lo otro, muy importante que debes añadir a la pregunta: ¿cómo estás ejecutando ese script?

Comment: @Alfabravo de acuerdo, edito mi pregunta

Comment: @Alfabravo ya está

Comment: Cuales son los permisos que tiene el archivo? Tiene la bandera de ejecutable puesta? Mira con `ls -l`

Comment: @eftshift0 `-rwxrwxr-- 1 miUser  miUser 464 jun 25 20:56 phpstorm_reset_trial.sh`

Comment: Se ve bien (si eres `miUser` o estás en el grupo `miUser`). Podrías colocar en la pregunta la línea de comandos que usas para intentar ejecutar y el error que te sale?

Comment: @eftshift0 la linea que uso para lanzar el script la puse al actualizar la pregunta, es la que empieza con `sh ..` , errores no muestra ninguno, simplemente sale el print del echo y ningun error.

Comment: Si lo ejecutas con `sh`, no debes necesitar los `#!` al principio. Cual es el error?

Comment: No tienen ningun error el output del comand, simplemente no hace lo que debe, y el comando q contiene si lo ejecuto diractamente en la consol si ba, que error da ? pues que no hace lo que le indico

Comment: los `echo` si sacan lo que quieres? O eso tampoco?

Comment: @eftshift0 los echos si estan  bien, solo falla el comando

Comment: @eftshift0 por cierto, el primer comentario de `#/bin/bash` lo  reconoce el sistema para hacer algo  o es meramente informativo ?

Comment: Linux no es como Güindous donde se infiere que porque la extensión es sh se debe utilizar bash y si es .py se debe usar python. El propio script debe indicar cual es su intérprete y para eso se usa la línea del _shebang_ (`#!/el/interprete/del/script`).

Comment: Todo suena como que entonces el archivo se debería borrar.... especialmente si el archivo existe... de no existir, te debería dar un mensaje de error.

Comment: Podrías hacer un script un poco más largo que primero verifique si el archivo existe y vas mostrando lo que quieres con echo. Por ejemplo (en un 1-liner porque no puedo formatear mucho en un comentario y asumiendo que estás corriendo bash): `if [ -f "${PATH_FILE}eval" ]; then echo El archivo existe. Lo vamos a borrar; rm "${PATH_FILE}eval"; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo hubo un error al borrar el archivo; fi; else echo El archivo no existe; fi`

Answer (score 2):

Más que respuésta, son recomendaciones:

1. Utiliza sólo un header. Cuando eres un desarrollador novato, te puede confundir; cuando eres uno más experimentado, te puede molestar. En ambos casos, es innecesario. Sólo escribe:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ...
   ```

   Y la terminal sabrá qué hacer cuando encuentre ese texto llamado *shebang*, o *shabang*. Tiene muchos nombres y siempre se pelean.
2. Pon entrecomillados lo que no sean parámetros ni comandos:

   ```
   rm -rf "${PATH_FILE}eval"
   echo "rm -rf ${PATH_FILE}eval"
   ```
3. No utilices rutas relativas, a menos que sea muy claro por qué lo vas a hacer y asegures que todos (incluyéndote tú dentro de 100 años y con resaca) lo van a entender:

   ```
   PATH_FILE='/home/<nombre de usuario>/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.1/'
   ```

   No sé cómo estés teniendo la salida de tu `$PATH_FILE`, pero quizás haya un conflicto con con que las comillas simples **no expanden ni sustituyen**.
4. Cuando hayas terminado de escribir tu código y **de haberle puesto el hashbang que corresponde a la ruta del programa que lo va a ejecutar**, dale permisos de ejecución para que lo puedas correr tan sólo ponendo la ruta a ese archivo ahora ejecutable:

   ```
    $ chmod u+x phpstorm_reset_trial.sh
   ```

   Y ya puedes correrlo, dentro de la carpeta donde se encuentra, con:

   ```
    $ ./phpstorm_reset_trial.sh
   ```

   O con la ruta completa:

   ```
    $ /<ruta completa>/phpstorm_reset_trial.sh
   ```

Estos consejos te van a servir para cuando lo quieras correr con tu crontab, ya que este programa usa una shell por defecto con características limitadas, y depende de cómo se invoque para respetar los permisos sobre otros archivos.

Comment: Primero gracias por tu tiempo, me has ayudado mucho. Pero hay una cosa que no termino de entender, es sobre el header y el 'ambito' de un script (con que se ejecutara). ¿Cual es la forma correcta de ejecutar un script? Es que he visto que a veces es `sh <file.sh>` y otras veces `./<file.sh>` y ¿por que a veces funciona con uno o con otro? Y una ultima cosa, para que sirve esa cabecera si siempre se ejecutar por la shell no ? Es que no termino de entender las diferentes formas de ejecutar un mismo script, si hay algun sitio donde leer al respecto para aclaracion te lo agradeceria.Muchas gracias

Comment: En Linux, no importa con que sufijo o extensión termine un archivo. Lo que importa es, 1) Si tiene permisos de ejecución, 2) El header. Sobre el header, los primeros bytes son importantes para saber con qué programa se va a correr.

Comment: A pesar de que es lo mismo ´bash script.sh´ que ´./script.sh´ cuando este último tiene un shebang ´!#/bin/bash´, es más práctico y menos verboso utilizarlo.

Comment: Y para nada es lo mismo `sh ./script` que `bash ./script` o `./script` con un shebang para bash. Esto es porque sh no es lo mismo que bash. `sh` usualmente se refiere a una shell un tanto limitada, pero universal, llamada `dash`, y no al bien conocido `bash`

Comment: Y sobre el sitio dónde leer sobre eso, pues es todo internet. Recuerdo que venía algo en el libro de Brian Kernighan sobre Unix. O creo que también en la famosa y polémica guía de Advanced Shell Scripting.
Eso de los números mágicos (bytes en el header) es bien interesante. Son parte de la base del comando `file`: `file <archivo a descubrir>`